# Latin term for "false equivalence" fallacy?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, rhetoric

I'm looking for a way to talk in Latin about the "blame on both sides" rhetoric with respect to the recent events in Charlottesville. Is there a Latin term for the fallacy of [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence)? It seems related to the [*argūmentum ad temperantiam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_to_moderation), but they're not exactly the same.